# Matrix norms and projections

Tags: matrices

Is it true that for matrices of any sizes (for which the following makes sense), that if $P$ is a symmetric PSD projection matrix,

$$\|APB\|_2 \leq \|AB\|_2?$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm?

Are there any conditions one can put on $A$ and $B$ that make this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counterexample: $APB=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1\\ &0}\pmatrix{1&0\\ -1&0}\ne0$, but $AB=0$.